# Is there a limit to how many association levels you can reference in a Where query?

Tags: grails, groovy, properties, associations, where-clause

This works:

```
def query = Idea.where {manager.id == id}
```

This doesn't work:

```
def query = Idea.where {manager.profile.riding.id == id}
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: In the future, using phrases like "doesn't work" without showing the error/exception text/stack... doesn't work.  We need more to really know what's going on.  Think domain classes, stack trace, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Construction Idea.where and Idea.withCriteria are not self-sufficient and not reliable. Always use construction Idea.createCriteria().

```
def riding = Riding.get(id)

def results = Idea.createCriteria().list() {

  manager{

     profile{
        eq('riding', riding)
     }

  }

}
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much.  This is exactly what I'm trying to do.  I'm going to try this now. Thanks for the advice/direction!!